# Javascript convert decimal power to regular decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, number-formatting

Using Javascript Math I can convert a decimal number like 100 into decimal power number like 1e+2

```
Math.pow(10, 2)
```

But how can I do it the other way round? How can I convert a decimal power like 1e+2 to a regular decimal like 100? I need this to save a number in a database number column.
I could not find any method or jquery plugin that will do this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you showed above, `Math.pow(10, 2)`, actually evaluates to `100`.

But if you are given the string `1e+2`, you can change it into `100` by calling `parseFloat()`:

```js
var s = '1e+2',         // This is a string in scientific notation.
    x = parseFloat(s);  // Here we convert it to the more widespread notation.
document.write('"'+s+'" -> '+x);  // Let's print out the values for testing purposes.
```

Comment: Yeah, converting was the wrong term. (Friday evening ^^) parseFloat und changing db column type to float worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is number formats, not numbers.

The string `"100"` is the textual representation of the number `100`. The string `"1e+2"` is the textual representation of the same number, but in scientific format.

A numeric value doesn't have any specific format. The values in the variables `a`, `b` and `c` in this code are completely identical:

```
var a = 100;
var b = Math.pow(10, 2);
var c = 1e+2;
```

A numeric value only gets a specific format when you create a textual represenation of the number. I this code the variables from the previous example are displayed as text:

```
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

As the values are not to small or too large to be resonably represented in the regular decimal format, that's how they come out:

```
100
100
100
```

When you want to store a numeric value in the database, it doesn't matter where the number came from, it's just the numeric value itself that is used.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow(x, y)` actually returns the result of x^y. In your specific case, it is being represented in scientific notation, but the actual number is still being 100.
If you have a **string** and want to get the actual number, you can use:

`Number("1e+2")`

**Example**

```js
$("#result").append(Number("1e+2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I think that you mean `Number("1E+2")`.